# Null and date format handling in talend

Tags: excel, postgresql, datetime, nullpointerexception, talend

I have an excel with a date field but the first row in the excel is blank and few other rows are having a date format as **MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss**.
The data to be loaded into a Postgresql table with the field of data type timestamp **yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss**. 
The excel cannot be modified as it is being downloaded from the cloud and the data is loaded straight away into the table.
I tried using tConvert type but it cannot accept null or " " values in timestamp.
 I am facing a Null tMap error during runtime in talend. Even if I try to convert from string to date format in order to pass null in tmap, it is changing the date format and showing error.How can this be handled ?

The talend structure is : 
 **tFileInputExcel - > TMAP(date field : MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss) -> tConvertType(date field : yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss) ->TMAP(yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss) -> Postgresql Table**

Here is the Excel screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, I do not quite understand why do you want to use tConvertType component. After defining a proper schema Talend is changing your data into Java Date object and from that moment format is not important and you don't have to convert it when you want to put it into Postgres table. At least it should not cause NullPointerException.

Consider following steps:

**Sample input file**

[image: input file with empty strings/spaces/nulls]

I've prepared some file with date value/space/empty string, solution I'm describing works also with nulls.

**Configure tFileInputExcel component**

You have to allow taking null values in by checking the Nullable check box. You should also check trim option.

[image: tFileInputExcel sample schema]

**Examine output**

After connecting input component to tLogRow null/empty/space values are handled properly.

[image: tLogRow with null values]

I hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture date format or null handling  in variable within tMAP component

that is

```
var :TalendDate.formatDate("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss",row1.columnname)
```

so data flow would be

tFileInputExcel --->tMAP --->Postgresql Table